# integral inequality involving $\cos^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to prove the following statement. 
Let $f$ be an integrable, monotonically increasing (possibly unbounded) function on the interval $[0,1]$ and $k$ be a monotonically increasing, bounded function on the same interval. Both $f$ and $k$ are positive.
Then for arbitrary $a$

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x)k(x)\cos^2(ax) \; dx \cdot \int_0^1 f(x) \; dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)\cos^2(ax) \; dx \cdot \int_0^1 f(x)k(x) \; dx
\end{align*}

Basically saying that putting $k$ in the integral with the cosine results in a smaller value. I have tried rewriting the statement in several ways, but all of no avail. I also tried using the integral mean value theorem, but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Also, I do not know whether the statement is actually true, it is just a hunch. If anyone has a counterexample or any ideas how I could go about proving it, I would be very grateful!

**Edit**: 
As noted in the comments, this could hold in the more general sense

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 g(x)k(x) \; dx \cdot \int_0^1 f(x) \; dx \leq \int_0^1 g(x) \; dx \cdot \int_0^1 f(x)k(x) \; dx
\end{align*}
for $g<f$. I was able to prove that it works for $0 \leq a \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, using that $cos^2$ is monotonically decreasing then. However, I am more interested in the case $\pi \leq a \leq \frac{3}{2} \pi$. Is the more general statement wrong?

**Edit 2:** The more general statement is wrong, e.g. $f(x)=e^x+1, g(x)=e^x, k(x)=\sqrt{x}$. So if its true at all, it is due to the additional constraints.

Comment: For $0\leq a\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ it's true.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg that would be a start.. How did you see that?

Comment: Dividing by $(\int_0^1 f)^2 > 0$, we have the random variable $x$ with law $\mu = \frac{fdx}{\int_0^1 f}$, and the inequality in question is $$\mathbb E_\mu [k(x) \cos^2(ax)] \le \mathbb E_\mu  k(x) \mathbb E_\mu [\cos^2(ax)]$$
Unfortunately, Cauchy-Schwarz gives
$$ \mathbb E_\mu [k(x) \cos^2(ax)] \le \sqrt{E_\mu [ k(x)^2]  \mathbb E_\mu [\cos^4(ax)]} $$

Comment: @Banana I used the definition of the definite integral.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I unfortunately really dont see how

Comment: You might want to consider something more abstract. Letting $g(x) = f(x)\cos^2 ax$, the inequality becomes $$\int_0^1 g(x)k(x)\,dx\int_0^1f(x)\,dx \le \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx\int_0^1f(x)k(x)\,dx$$Which now can be generalized to any positive increasing (if needed) $g \le f$. If you can show this form, yours follows (at least for $a \le \pi/2$ if you needed to have $g$ increasing). This  general form may prove more enlightening than your specific one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks! Unfortunately, and against my intuition, the more general statement is wrong, see my edit!

Comment: That is why I said it might be "more enlightening", instead of a solution. Now you should look at your counter-example and consider what makes it fail, and why $\cos^2 ax$ might work instead (assuming it really does).